# Change color on Bokeh: plot.patches with respect to a Select widget

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to change the colors of my plot.patches with respect to the value of selected_column which can be changed in a widget Select.

However my callback seems to have no effect.

Here is my code

```
# SQL query
# =========
# Get number of building per departement for each family
geodf = {}
for i, fam in enumerate(['2', '3A', '3B', '4', 'IGH']):
    print('famille: ', fam)
    sql_famille_departement = get_sql_famille_dep(fam)
    with engine.connect() as connection : 
         geodf[fam] = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql_famille_departement, connection, geom_col='geom_departement')
    
    # Rename column
    geodf[fam].rename(columns={'nb_batiment': fam}, inplace=True)
    
    if i == 0:
        merged_geodf = geodf[fam]
    else:
        merged_geodf = merged_geodf.merge(geodf[fam][[fam, 'id']], on='id', how='left')

merged_geodf.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Data treatment
# ==============
# Convert the GeoDataFrame to GeoJSON format
geojson_data = json.loads(merged_geodf.to_json())

# Create a GeoJSONDataSource with the GeoJSON data
data = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=json.dumps(geojson_data))

# Choose a famille incendie to display
selected_column = '2'

# A dict to specify for each column, the min and max values for the colors and the number of possible colors
min_max_ncolors = {'2': (1, 80000, 9), '3A': (1, 10000, 6), '3B': (1, 1000, 6), '4': (1, 600, 7), 'IGH': (1, 50, 6)}

# Color to display
# ================
# Define a custom palette with 'white' as the first color and 'Reds' for the remaining colors
custom_palette = ["white", *palettes.Reds[min_max_ncolors[selected_column][2]][::-1]]
custom_palette = custom_palette[:1] + custom_palette[3:]

# Create a linear color mapper with the 'Reds' colormap
color_mapper_bar = LinearColorMapper(palette=custom_palette, low=min_max_ncolors[selected_column][0], high=min_max_ncolors[selected_column][1])

list_color_mapper = {}
for key in min_max_ncolors.keys():
    local_palette = ["white", *palettes.Reds[min_max_ncolors[key][2]][::-1]]
    local_palette = custom_palette[:1] + custom_palette[3:]
    list_color_mapper[key] = linear_cmap(field_name=key, palette=local_palette, low=min_max_ncolors[key][0], high=min_max_ncolors[key][1])

# Create bokeh plot
# =================
# Picture size
r = 920/800 # DON'T CHANGE
height = 1000

# Create the Bokeh plot
plot = figure(title="Carte de France", width=round(height*r), height=height,
              x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None, x_axis_label=None, y_axis_label=None)

# Plot the geometries as patches
map_fr = plot.patches('xs', 'ys', source=data, fill_alpha=0.7, line_color=None, line_width=1,
             fill_color=list_color_mapper[select_column])

# Manage Select widget and change
# ===============================
# Create a Select widget to choose the column
column_select = Select(title="Famille incendie", value=selected_column, options=list(min_max_ncolors.keys()))

# Attach a CustomJS callback to the Select widget to update the color mapper and fill color
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(plot=plot, map_fr=map_fr,data=data, list_color_mapper=list_color_mapper, column_select=column_select), code="""
    const selected_value = column_select.value;
    const minMax = {'2': [1, 80000, 9], '3A': [1, 1000, 6], '3B': [1, 1000, 6], '4': [1, 1000, 7], 'IGH': [1, 50, 6]};
    const color_mapper = list_color_mapper[selected_value];
    map_fr.glyph.fill_color.transform = color_mapper;
    map_fr.change.emit();
""")

# Attach the CustomJS callback to the Select widget
column_select.js_on_change('value', callback)

# Show the plot and the Select widget together in a column layout
layout = column(plot, column_select)


# Get the HTML code for the plot
html_code = file_html(layout, 'inline', "My Bokeh Plot")


# Save the HTML code to a file
with open("bokeh_plot.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(html_code)
```

I also tried to add a random color on event, but nothing change.
I would expect also to change '''data''' but I don't know how.

In addtion, the way

```
map_fr = plot.patches('xs', 'ys', source=data, fill_alpha=0.7, line_color=None, line_width=1,
             fill_color=list_color_mapper[select_column]
```

knows the right column to choose in the data is not perfectly clear for me.